# Unable to fetch data via getInitialProps in Next.Js after deploying to AWS, but works on development environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have page in Next.js app in which I am trying to fetch data via **getInitialProps** which works fine when I am testing it in development mode, but it does not work after I deployed to AWS. I am trying to set Meta tags so that I can social share for dynamic pages.

I tried to set Meta tags via state but it does not work as if we get access to state after component is mounted and facebook debugger is unable to find my Meta tags. I am using a class component and code for getInitialProps looks like this

```
static async getInitialProps({ query }) {
        const resp = await axios.get('/product/fetchSingleProduct/' + query.pid)
        console.log(query.pid)
        const data = await resp.data
        return { data }
     }
```

As I said before it does work in development environment and I am able to see `console.log(query.pid)` on my terminal. But after deployment I get the error message as follow:

```
exception: {…}
kind: "ObjectId"
message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"undefined\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Product\""
name: "CastError"
path: "_id"
stringValue: "\"undefined\""
value: "undefined"
```

As request below is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "start": "next start",
    "build": "next build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.17",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "event-emitter": "^0.3.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "next": "^7.0.3",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-countup": "^4.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-facebook": "^8.0.4",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.4",
    "react-image-magnify": "^2.7.4",
    "react-modal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-notifications": "^1.4.3",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.8.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "styled-theming": "^2.2.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "url-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you and happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at some cases: (These might be the problems during deployment)

1. Try deleting proxy if existed in package.json . (This may be caused due to proxy)
2. As your error message, it might have some problem in your backend too. Check it once again.
3. Checkout your .gitignore as it might content /build which wont upload the build file. Comment it.
4. Checkout the network request if is hitting the required uri or not.

Just sharing the problems which might occurs frequently during deployment. Hope it will help u somewhere sometime.

Also, upload your package.json and .gitignore file to have a great view on your problem.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do not have proxy in my package.json and I building my package before I am deploying. I do have reverse proxy though on nginx server. I am fetching the same url twice so I am not sure which one is getting connected.

Comment: Also I am not sure if we can check the request of getInitialProps in network tab